Asynchronous Record Triggered Flow is never triggered when activated
As I'm new to SF Development, I believe it's possible I missed something. My understanding is that cannot make an external call (Google Distance Matrix) unless I have an Asynchronous flow.
I have run this using Debug, and the logs validate that it's doing what I want. When I activate this flow and update a record it doesn't seem to be triggered.
Since this is in a development org for my company at the moment, I have this set to run on create and update; this will be further refined with conditions once I can verify the thing actually runs.
I cannot share actual code for this because it's under an NDA, but this is a a generic version of the class.
Again, this works when running under Debug. So I'm just trying to understand how it couldn't run when all conditions are met and it's activated.
public sharing with DeliveryRateController {
    @InvocableMethod(callout=true)
    public static void updateDeliveryRate(List<Id> ids) {
       List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();

       // Queries leads and stores them in a List
       List<Lead> leads = // SOQL

       // Loop through leads
       for(Lead lead : leads) {
       // --> Call the calcualteDistance method
       // --> Set the delivery rate 
       // --> Add the updated lead to the list of leads to update
       }
       // update leadsToUpdate
    }

    public static Decimal calcualteDistance(String origin, String destination) {
        // Calls the Google Distance Matrix API
        // Returns a value converted from meters to miles
    }

}



Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

@identigral thank you. I did read those and I've updated this with a very generic version of the apex class that is called.

What is the entry criteria for the flow?

@RenatoOliveira the only entry criteria is delivery rate is null
